# Doxygen-filter-perl listing private and protected methods in public member functions

Tags: perl, doxygen

I am documenting Perl project with Doxygen, for that I am using doxygen-filter-perl to make it work with perl. Everything is working fine except for one thing, which is, if I document protected/private method it is listing under public member functions section. I want to have three separate modules for each kind of methods. i.e. public, private and protected and not only PUBLIC member functions.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as private or protected methods in Perl. You can tell people that they shouldn't look at a method by prefixing it with an underscore, but the interpreter doesn't actually prevent anyone from calling it.

Comment: I am familiar with that, but I want to show in documentation that which methods can be called from which file. That is why.

Comment: The standard in Perl is to only document the public API. If it's not documented, people shouldn't be calling it.